# Throwing error inside function, but not outside

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have been using the constants and variables I have here inside of the dbconnect function to allow direct access to my core data variables.

When I enter the code like this it works:

```
    @IBAction func createNewGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("StudioData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let studioData = StudioData(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
    if let err = error {
        println(err.localizedFailureReason)
    } else {
        println("Studio Created")
    }
    studioData.studioname = studioNameText.text
    studioData.execFirstName = firstNameText.text
    studioData.execLastName = lastNameText.text
}
```

But when its like this it returns "Unresolved identifier studioData"

```
    @IBAction func createNewGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    dbconnect()
    studioData.studioname = studioNameText.text
    studioData.execFirstName = firstNameText.text
    studioData.execLastName = lastNameText.text
}

func dbconnect () {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("StudioData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let studioData = StudioData(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
    if let err = error {
        println(err.localizedFailureReason)
    } else {
        println("Studio Created")
    }

}
```

I am trying to put the code into a function to reduce duplication between different functions.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the variable `studioData` is not defined in `createNewGame(sender:)`.  Since you want to use the result of `dbconnect()` I recommend passing the created object back to the caller.  There are many ways to accomplish this but here is one:

```
@IBAction func createNewGame(sender: AnyObject) {
    var studioData = dbconnect()
    studioData.studioname = studioNameText.text
    studioData.execFirstName = firstNameText.text
    studioData.execLastName = lastNameText.text
}

func dbconnect () -> StudioData {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("StudioData", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let studioData = StudioData(entity: entityDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    var error: NSError?
    managedObjectContext?.save(&error)
    if let err = error {
        println(err.localizedFailureReason)
    } else {
        println("Studio Created")
    }
    return studioData
}
```